# Vuetify: How to arrange several v-card-actions buttons?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to unify my v-card-actions of my v-cards in Vuetify. My goal is to center the test button in my v-card and place it over the like and share "footer" buttons. I want to place the like and share footer at the end of my v-card and justify space between them.

I tried putting the "footer" with the `<v-flex class="d-flex justify-space-between mx-4">...</v-flex>` into the v-card actions, and use CSS parameters absolute and bottom as described in this answer from another user https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jsodz?fontsize=14. But the buttons are not centered anymore, and the space between the like and share button disappears.

As one can see in the picture, I want to place the footer and the Test buttons on the bottom, but when I tried, the test button didn't center, or the footer buttons were not divided anymore.
[image: I want to place the test and footer buttons on the bottom. It doesn´t work propperly.]
This is the best-looking code that I have got so far:

```
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4 lg3 v-for="project in filteredProjects" :key="project.title">
      <v-card class="ma-3" hover height="95%" >
        <v-card-text>
          ...
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-btn class="green accent-4 white--text">                  
              <span class="">Test</span>                  
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-card-actions>
        <v-flex class="d-flex justify-space-between mx-4">
          <div>
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>thumb_up</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span class="text-md-subtitle-2 black--text font-weight-bold ">{{ project.upvoteCount }}</span>
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>thumb_down</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span class="text-md-subtitle-2 black--text font-weight-bold ">{{ project.downvoteCount }}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>share</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span class="text-md-subtitle-2 black--text font-weight-bold">Teilen</span>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

Thank you very much for your tips!
Kind regards.

Comment: What you're looking for is `v-spacer` between your buttons. just use another `v-card-actions` after the test one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FacelessTimma, It is possible to move the card actions to the bottom by using css helpers from vuetify

You need to use d-flex and the flex direction to grow either **flex-row or flex-column**

and important think is to use **class="grow"** for which the dynamic content can grow in your card

Here in the below code, the trick is to use
**class="d-flex flex-row" in each columns
class="d-flex flex-column" in each card
class="grow" in each v-card-text component**

Please find the below working code

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
      <v-row>
    <v-col v-for="project in filteredProjects" :key="project.title" class="d-flex flex-row col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <v-card class="d-flex flex-column" hover width="100%">
        <v-card-text class="grow">
          {{project.description}}
         </v-card-text>
        <v-card-text class="pa-0">
          <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-btn class="green accent-4 white--text">                  
              <span class="">Test</span>                  
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-row justify="space-around-between" class="ma-2">
            <v-col class="px-0">
              <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>thumb_up</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span class="text-md-subtitle-2 black--text font-weight-bold ">{{ project.upvoteCount }}</span>
            </v-col>
            <v-col class="px-0">
              <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>thumb_down</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span class="text-md-subtitle-2 black--text font-weight-bold ">{{ project.downvoteCount }}</span>
            </v-col>
            <v-col class="px-0"><v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>share</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span class="text-md-subtitle-2 black--text font-weight-bold">Teilen</span></v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
      return {
        filteredProjects: [
          {
            title: 'some title 1',
            description: 'some description some description some description some description some description some description some description some description',
            upvoteCount: 12,
            downvoteCount: 34,
          },
          {
            title: 'some title 2',
            description: 'some description',
            upvoteCount: 12,
            downvoteCount: 34,
          },
          {
            title: 'some title 3',
            description: 'some description',
            upvoteCount: 12,
            downvoteCount: 34,
          }
        ]
      }
  },
})
```

Please find the working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/RwKRzqW